# Sequence of differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of differentaible functions on $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ converging uniformly to a function $f$ on $[0,1]$, Then

1. $f$ is differentiable and Riemann integrable there
2. $f$ is uniformly continuous and R-integrable
3. $f$ is continuous, need not be differentiable on $(0,1)$ and need not be R-integrable on $ [0,1]$,
4. $f$ need not be continuous.

Well I think 2 is only correct statement  as every $f_n$ are differentiable on $[0,1]$ hence uniformly contnous, and as they converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$ so $f$ is uniformly continuous and every continuous function is rieman integrable..Am I correct?

Comment: Why do you think that? Do you have a proof of 2.? Do you have counterexamples for the other statements?

Comment: the proof for 2 is as every $f_n$ are differentiable on $[0,1]$ hence uniformly contnous, and as they converge uniformly to $f$ on [0,1] so $f$ is uniformly continous and every continous function is rieman integrable.

Comment: Convolve $|x-\frac{1}{2}|$ with smooth approximate identity functions for a counterexample to 1.  The uniform limit of Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable so 3 is false and 2 is true (uniform limit of continuous is continuous and continuous on compact is uniformly continuous).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple counterexample to 1 is the sequence $f_n(x)=\sqrt{(x-1/2)^2+1/n}$, which converges uniformly to non-differentiable function $f(x)=|x-1/2|$.

2 is correct: uniform convergence preserves uniform continuity, and uniform continuity implies Riemann integrability. It follows that 3 and 4 are false.